# JQuery .isNumeric

Tags: jquery

I have a text box with an id of EmpNum. I cannot figure out how to use jQuery's isNumeric to check to see if the value is numeric or not.

I tried:

```
    ('#.EmpNum').IsNumeric
```

but that did not work.

Comment: what's ('#.EmpNum')? i suppose you mean $("#EmpNum")..

Comment: The documentation is here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isNumeric/ You have to understand the difference between methods and static functions...

Answer (score 49, accepted):

according to http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isNumeric/

it's :`jQuery.isNumeric(value)`

so, it should be `$.isNumeric($("#EmpNum").val())`

Answer (score 15):

Shouldn't it be more like...

```
if($.isNumeric($('#EmpNum').val()))
```

Comment: This answer is correct; here's the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isNumeric/) to compliment his answer.

Answer (score 5):

Pass in the value as an argument to isNumeric. Also make sure you are using jQuery version 1.7 as this was added in 1.7.

```
$.isNumeric( $('#EmpNum').val() )
```

Answer (score 4):

it should be like this

```
$.isNumeric($('#EmpNum').val());
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what version of jQuery you are using, but as "$.isNumeric()" function is deprecated (https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#breaking-change-jquery-isnumeric-and-custom-tostring) since jQuery Core 3.0 Update, I found a custom solution for this problem (originally posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9716488/3323790):

```
function isNumeric(n) {
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You Should use simple and easy way like:

var value=$('#txtNumber').val();

if($.isNumeric(value))

{

//write your code here

}

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$.isNumeric($('#EmpNum').text())
```

Also the [isNumeric method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isNumeric/) was only added in version 1.7, which version are you using?

[See here for jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/mupTA/)

Answer (score 0):

For me `$.isNumeric($('#EmpNum').val());` did not work.

I had to use this:

```
var temp = $('#EmpNum').val();

$.isNumeric(temp);
```