# Pure JavaScript: a function like jQuery's isNumeric()

Tags: javascript

Is there is any function like `isNumeric` in pure JavaScript?

I know jQuery has this function to check the integers.

Comment: Try `value => !isNan(+value)`

Comment: isNaN()

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN

Comment: Wanted to add in isInteger (please note floats are not integers) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger

Answer (score 672, accepted):

There's no `isNumeric()` type of function, but you could add your own:

```
function isNumeric(n) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
```

**NOTE: Since [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) is not a proper way to check for numeric it should NOT be used.**

Comment: This solution is used in / taken from Jquery library $.isNumeric(obj) http://api.jquery.com/jquery.isnumeric/

Comment: @Matt My comment was aimed at the comment and the note in the answer stating `parseInt` was the wrong way of doing this (then going ahead and using `parseFloat`, which doesn't really seem different). Interestingly `isFinite` will get you the result you're after in almost all cases on its own (apart from whitespace strings, which for some reason return `true`), so `parseInt` vs `parseFloat` seems irrelevant in this context. I certainly can't find a single input to that function where `parseInt` makes a difference.

Comment: @Thor84no http://jsfiddle.net/fNPvf/17918/

Comment: I'll grant you the difference on `'.\d+'`, I missed that, but the JS console is more useful than that fiddle. Either way, that's the appropriate answer, not whatever the stuff about short-circuiting `&&`s was about. It does feel like there should be a better way than this though since `isFinite` covers almost everything on its own. I did a fiddle of my own to have a play: http://jsfiddle.net/d5cxdwue/1/

Comment: DON'T USE THIS FUNCTION it does not work with floats. See jQuery's [`isNumeric`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/bf48c21d225c31f0f9b5441d95f73615ca3dcfdb/src/core.js#L206)  here for ideas on implementing it.

Comment: isFinite( "0" ) is true.. that's why you should use the more robust Number.isFinite( "0" ) which returns false ;)

Comment: I would argue though that `Infinity` is numeric though not a number.  So if you're using this to sum all the numerics in an array, and one of them is `Infinity`, probably it should be `Infinity`.  But of course if there is also a `-Infinity`, you should understandably get NaN (which is what javascript yields.)

Comment: @Thor84no *parseInt* doesn't deal correctly with numbers in their exponential form. Consider following example: parseInt(1000000000000000000000, 10) will return 1, while parseFloat(1000000000000000000000) will return 1e+21, because parseInt try to parse "1e+21"

Comment: Since in my case, only integers and floats (non-exponential) are valid, I added this to the top of the function: `if (n.toUpperCase().includes('E')) return false;` This protects against accidental exponents, e.g. 24e4. Technically, this is numeric, but in most front-end apps, an alpha character in a numeric field should trigger a validation error.

Comment: don't work for me. bug for brazilian format.
`isNumeric('1,2');`

best solution: https://github.com/adamwdraper/Numeral-js

Comment: Using `parseFloat()` instead of `Number()` has inconsistent behavior across ECMAScript specifications when parsing exponential notation. In contrast, `Number()` has always been able to handle it. The downside of `Number()` is that the entire string must be numeric, and not just the start of the string.

Comment: This solution will return `true` for `"123a"` and such.. (number with a string).

Comment: Don't use this if you want to check that a string is actually, strictly, numeric. Just fixed bugs in my app because a dev must have found this solution (hello there) to validate text input as numeric... but it accepts `123abc` as numeric.

Comment: For future readers, many of the comments above need to be ignored due to them being discussion about one of the earlier edits of this answer (there are 5 atm).  I'm using this exact function and am having no issues. `"123a"` returns `false` and as does `"123abs"`.  As far as I can tell it works perfectly!

Comment: What about `Number.isInteger()`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger

Comment: Careful. This function returns true for single element arrays containing a numeric element: ```isNumeric([0]) === true``` and ```isNumeric(['123']) === true```

Comment: @TimboWhite if a single element array containing a numeric element is a concern would this be a possible solution?

function isNumeric(n) {
  if (Array.isArray(n) && n.length === 1)
   return false;
  else
   return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
 }

Comment: DOES NOT WORK
console.log(isNumeric('233,234.34')); // FALSE...
console.log(isNumeric('233.234,34')); // FALSE

Answer (score 210):

This should help:

```
function isNumber(n) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
```

Very good link: [Validate decimal numbers in JavaScript - IsNumeric()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082/validate-numbers-in-javascript-isnumeric)

Answer (score 109):

```
function IsNumeric(val) {
    return Number(parseFloat(val)) == val;
}
```

Comment: I think the updated version of this is actually the best answer here. I find it odd that it has the least up-votes. I thought at first that it might fail if `IsNumeric` was called with `NaN`, but due to the quirk of NaN that it's not equal to anything it actually works out fine.

Comment: And I think you can also drop the cast to `Number()` and rely on the double equals to do a bit of conversion:

`let isNumeric = (val) => parseFloat(val) == val;`

Comment: As per my requirement which I believe many other developers would have it should be

function IsNumeric(val) {
    return Number(val)==val;
}

So that it ignores in case of empty string. Because I only want to validate if there is invalid value entered. While allowing empty string which is not number.

I think all three answers are good based on scenarios

Comment: Explain the code please. Why not `Number(val).toString() == val.toString()`?

Comment: if Val is undefined then .ToString will throw exception

Comment: I'm not sure I'm getting this answer. The string "96" is not numeric because Number("96") does not strictly equal "96". Shouldn't it be numeric?

Comment: You can try As per my requirement which I believe many other developers would have it should be

function IsNumeric(val) {
    return Number(val)==val;
}

So that it ignores in case of empty string. Because I only want to validate if there is invalid value entered. While allowing empty string which is not number.

I think all three answers are good based on scenarios

Comment: It is bad practice to check equals on two floating point numbers

Comment: Does not work! See example here...
https://jsfiddle.net/chris76326/excd4p86/4/

Comment: someone edited it to make it not work try updated code

Answer (score 22):

There is Javascript function [isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) which will do that.

```
isNaN(90)
=>false
```

so you can check numeric by

```
!isNaN(90)
=>true
```

Comment: except for "" and true and false which are not-not-a-number ...

Comment: I get `isNaN(null) === false`

Comment: `isNaN("null") === true; isNaN(null) === false;` for me too

Comment: `isNaN(true) === false; isNaN(false) === false;`

Comment: console.log(isNaN('34.234,23')); // true :-(

Answer (score 19):

```
var str = 'test343',
    isNumeric = /^[-+]?(\d+|\d+\.\d*|\d*\.\d+)$/;

isNumeric.test(str);
```

Comment: Well, depending on the use case, it might actually be the worst answer here. For example, this returns `false` against `' 1'` or `'0x01'`, localization is not taken into account...

Comment: I kinda like this answer better, if you are reading chunks from a string or an user input, isNaN and parseInt can result in unwanted false positives like "123abc", "2e1", "0x2", etc.. (even jQuery.isNumeric will parse true). I would use something like this `function isNumeric(str) { return /^\d*\.{0,1}\d*$/.test(str); }`

Comment: Well, depending on the use case, it might actually be the best answer here.

Comment: As long as you trim strings and aren't worried about alternative representations this is a reasonable answer.

Comment: You didn't cater for Locale. Thousands and Decimal separators can be other way around in some countries.

Answer (score 12):

**isFinite(String(n))** returns true for n=0 or '0', '1.1' or 1.1,

but false for '1 dog' or '1,2,3,4', +- Infinity and any NaN values.

Comment: isFinite(null) -->  true,    isFinite([]) --> true,   isFinite('') true

Comment: As of ES2015 there is [Number.isFinite](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isFinite)