# How to make a table cell in the editable HTML table to accept numbers only (no letters)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, edit

I am working with HTML5, JavaScript, JQuery.

Comment: use `inline editing` and `HTML5 Regex` for it

Comment: parseFloat($('#cell_id').val()) shoudlnt' be NaN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an [$.isNumeric()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isNumeric/) function in jQuery 1.7, otherwise you'll have to write your own function in Javascript - there's [a few answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9716468/is-there-any-function-like-isnumeric-in-javascript-to-validate-numbers) on that already.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is very similar to [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995183/how-to-allow-only-numeric-0-9-in-html-inputbox-using-jquery) but there might be a better answer. This following [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eSdYn/) works for your case.
I used the same code as in the mentioned question

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".only-numbers").keydown(function(event) {
        // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, and enter
         if ( event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 9 || event.keyCode == 27 || event.keyCode == 13 || 
              // Allow: Ctrl+A
             (event.keyCode == 65 && event.ctrlKey === true) || 
             // Allow: home, end, left, right
             (event.keyCode >= 35 && event.keyCode <= 39)) {
             // let it happen, don't do anything
             return;
        }
        else {
            // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
            if (event.shiftKey || (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) && (event.keyCode < 96 || event.keyCode > 105 )) {
                event.preventDefault(); 
            }   
    }
});
```

});