# Jquery check if value is numeric

Tags: jquery, numeric

I was wondering if anybody had a quick and dirty jquery method that will check if a value is numeric or not?  I was thinking about using a regex type method to check the value, if not do not submit the form.  I was using jquery validation, but I am running into issues just loading jquery validation.

I just have one value that I want to make sure is numeric.

Comment: See several others e.g http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9716468/is-there-any-function-like-isnumeric-in-javascript-to-validate-numbers

Comment: You can't do a simple parse as it will sometimes return a number from a non-numeric string - try `console.log(parseInt("10px", 10))`

Answer (score 58):

Sure, use jQuery's **[isNumeric()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isNumeric/)** function.

```
$.isNumeric("-10");  // true
$.isNumeric(16);     // true
$.isNumeric(0xFF);   // true
$.isNumeric("0xFF"); // true
$.isNumeric("8e5");  // true (exponential notation string)
$.isNumeric(3.1415); // true
$.isNumeric(+10);    // true
$.isNumeric(0144);   // true (octal integer literal)
$.isNumeric("");     // false
$.isNumeric({});     // false (empty object)
$.isNumeric(NaN);    // false
$.isNumeric(null);   // false
$.isNumeric(true);   // false
$.isNumeric(Infinity); // false
$.isNumeric(undefined); // false
```

Comment: some times it will give TypeError: $.isNumeric is not a function then use jquery.isNumeric() function

Comment: also getting a TypeError

Comment: +1 because you write in comments the result of each call compared to jquery web site documentation.

Comment: Note: `$.isNumeric("1,234"); // false `

Comment: Note: This API has been deprecated in jQuery 3.3.