# How to check if a string is an int?

Tags: jquery, string

I have a small if where I'd just like to check a string to see if it is an integer. I am using JQuery to do this.

JQUERY:

```
 var intRegex = /[0-9 -()+]+$/;


 if ($('#txtGRCSelect').val() != '' && intRegex($('#txtGRCSelect').val())) {
                        alert("No CASE");
                        $("#ErrorBoxText").html("Error : A Role has not been selected.");
                        rt = true;
                    }
```

It doesn't work, can anybody help me and tell me why?

Comment: @ArunPJohny Sorry, realised I forgot to add it in, it's now added

Comment: @nikhil Hi, this didnt work either

Comment: Surely a regular expression test for an integer should be something more like `/^[-+]?\d+$/`? Your current test would validate `asdjhiujb2-(+)`.

Comment: @Phylogenesis I have changed the regex according to suggestions, still not getting any results

Comment: `if (! /^[-+]?\d+$/.test($('#txtGRCSelect').val())) { /* Not a valid integer */ }`. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nnh1njg8/).

Comment: use jQuery.isNumeric(): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14464213/jquery-check-if-value-is-numeric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`intRegex` is a regex object so call the test method which will return true is the string satisfies the regex

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  var intRegex = /^[0-9 -()+]+$/; //may have to add `^` at the beginning to check the string is completely matches the regex, else it will just test whether the string ends with the given characters
  if ($('#txtGRCSelect').val() == '' || !intRegex.test($('#txtGRCSelect').val())) {
    alert("No CASE");
    $("#ErrorBoxText").html("Error : A Role has not been selected.");
    rt = true;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="txtGRCSelect" />
<button>Test</button>
```

Comment: Hi, I presumed you meant the 'test' method? This did not work either as it hasn't reached my alert.

Comment: @ArunPJohny `intRegex.text(` should be `test(`

Answer (score 0):

```
var ex=/^[0-9]*$/;
var A=$('#txtGRCSelect').val();
if(ex.test(A)==true)
{
alert("Value integer.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Method 1

```
function IsNumeric(x){    
var patt = new RegExp("^[0-9]+$");    
return patt.test(x);
}
```

Method 2

```
function IsNumeric(x){
x=x.replace('.','#');
return!isNaN(parseFloat(x))&&isFinite(x);
}
```

example:

```
IsNumeric(1)
```