# IsNumeric() similar function to js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vb6

I have a code that takes some numbers from a user.I want to ensure that the data given from the user are numbers and not strings.From my knowledge to vb6 I know i can use IsNumeric so I was wondering if there is any similar function to js

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082/validate-decimal-numbers-in-javascript-isnumeric

Comment: isFinite() is the closest match

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `isNaN()` and pass a string or number to it. It will return true or false. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var input = 1;
console.log(typeof input === "number");
```

See [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)

```js
var input1 = 1, input2 = "1";
console.log(typeof input1 === "number", typeof input2 === "number");
```

Answer (score 0):

Per the question previously asked here:
[Is there any function like IsNumeric in javascript to validate numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9716468/is-there-any-function-like-isnumeric-in-javascript-to-validate-numbers)

You can find an elegant function to create within your own library as follows:

```
function isNumeric(n) {
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
```