# Defaulting variable value if parameter type mismatch, in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a function with an optional parameter.  I'm defaulting the value to 1000 if the parameter isn't supplied like so:

```
function zoom( coords, zoomSpeed){
  zoomSpeed = zoomSpeed || 1000;
  //rest of code
}
```

This works for testing presence of the parameter, but I also want to make sure a number was supplied as the parameter.  I'm using the following but it seems like there is a better way to do this.

```
function zoom( coords, zoomSpeed){
  if (typeof zoomSpeed === "number"){
    zoomSpeed = zoomSpeed;
  }else{
    zoomSpeed = 1000;
  }
  //rest of code
}
```

Any feedback on a better way to do this would be appreciated.

Comment: What if somebody passes in the string "100". Is that okay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

... or

`zoomSpeed = parseInt(zoomSpeed) || 1000`

Comment: `zoomSpeed = +zoomSpeed || 0;`

Comment: Should be `|| 1000` and hopefully the value can not be zero passed in.

Comment: if  `defaultValue = 1000` and `zoomSpeed = 0` result will equal defaultValue. (`zoomSpeed = 1000` not `0`)

Comment: Of course I meant `|| 1000`, corrected and yes, it does not handle the case when the desired input value is zero, that's true.

Answer (score 4):

This is shorter:

```
if (typeof zoomSpeed !== "number"){
    zoomSpeed = 1000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use your `zoom(..., "5")` through following code

```
function zoom( coords, zoomSpeed){
  zoomSpeed = Number(zoomSpeed) !== NaN ? Number(zoomSpeed): 1000;
  //... 
}
```

Comment: Also, there is other version http://stackoverflow.com/q/9716468/4365315, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082/validate-decimal-numbers-in-javascript-isnumeric

Comment: or, just use this `zoomSpeed = Number(zoomSpeed) || 1000;`