# Angular, underscore, plucked array, sorting

Tags: javascript, angularjs, underscore.js

I got the unique product grades and product last delivered plucked from the products object so I can put them into a dropdown as a filter using underscore. How can I sort the product grades and last delivered dates using underscore or angular before I put them into the drop down?

product_grades = ["", "40", "20", "30", "35", "45", "50", "60"]

product_last_delivered = ["2015-07-29T00:00:00.000+08:00", "2015-04-10T00:00:00.000+08:00", "2015-11-19T00:00:00.000+08:00", "2015-01-05T00:00:00.000+08:00", "2015-11-18T00:00:00.000+08:00", "2015-11-04T00:00:00.000+08:00", "2015-04-01T00:00:00.000+08:00", "2015-11-13T00:00:00.000+08:00", "2014-10-15T00:00:00.000+08:00", "2015-10-24T00:00:00.000+08:00", "1899-12-31T23:36:42.000+07:36", "2015-10-20T00:00:00.000+08:00", "2015-06-17T00:00:00.000+08:00", "2015-11-14T00:00:00.000+08:00", "2015-03-12T00:00:00.000+08:00", "2015-07-18T00:00:00.000+08:00", "2015-07-27T00:00:00.000+08:00", "2015-09-21T00:00:00.000+08:00", "2015-10-07T00:00:00.000+08:00"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two ways of doing that. First using the native `sort`, the second using underscore.

**Helpers.**

```
function descending(a, b) {return b - a;}
function str2date(s) {return new Date(s);}
function isNumeric(n) {return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);}
```

**Using [Array.prototype.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)**

```
// To sort the grades, first eliminate the non-numbers and then sort.
product_grades.filter(isNumeric).sort(descending);

// To sort the dates, first convert strings to dates and then sort them.
product_last_delivered.map(str2date).sort(descending)
```

**Using Underscore's [_.sortBy](http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy)**

```
_.sortBy(product_grades.filter(isNumeric), descending)
_.sortBy(product_last_delivered.map(str2date), descending)
```

**Credits.**

`isNumeric` is from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9716488/2672370) wonderful answer by [DemoUser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/350858/demouser).

Comment: I am having trouble with [100, 150, 175, 200, 225, 75, NaN] as result using .sort() for product grades.

Comment: @ShinonChan Sure, np.