# How to identify a number from a var value?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, client-side-validation

I am receiving var value by:

```
var val=document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHoldermain_TextBox1').value;
```

In my code I am checking type of each character using 'typeof'. But always it is returning string only. How to identify the number?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validate decimal numbers in JavaScript - IsNumeric()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082/validate-decimal-numbers-in-javascript-isnumeric)

Comment: isNaN is a JavaScript function to let you know if a string is not a number.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN

Answer (score 2):

You can use `parseInt` or `parseFloat`. If `parseInt(str)` returns `NaN` so your string is not a number.

You can use only for strings that contains only digits: `parseInt('123')`. If it possible that your string can contains letters too so you can get some problems:

```
parseInt('123') // -> 123
parseInt('123asd') // '123asd' is not a number but parseInt returns 123
```

So more simple way is to use `jQuery`'s [`isNumeric`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/bf48c21d225c31f0f9b5441d95f73615ca3dcfdb/src/core.js#L206) function or implement it by yourself

You can see more about it from the link in the @Rahat's comment.

Also you can see at [this blog post](https://pietschsoft.com/post/2008/01/14/javascript-inttryparse-equivalent)

Comment: You should not use parseInt or parseFloat for this purpose. Reason explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9716468/is-there-any-function-like-isnumeric-in-javascript-to-validate-numbers

Comment: I have to select each element from the val and need to identify whether it is number or not? @Rahat

Comment: @Sachin No, you just can use `isNaN` function as @ThanNgoHoai mentioned earlier (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35619682/how-to-identify-a-number-from-a-var-value/35619712?noredirect=1#comment58922084_35619682)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with alternative answer but I think `parseInt` and `parseFloat` should be used for parsing because they are meant for it. `isNaN` function can give you numeric checking functionality.

```
function isNumber(val) {
  if(val == "") {
    return false;
  }
  return !isNaN(val);
}
```

As per comment, if you want to select number from array then you can simply create loop and call it inside. e.g

```
var vals = ['dsds','2','','4'];
for (var i = 0; i<vals.length; i++) {
  if(isNumber(vals[i]) {
    // it's number
  }
  else {
    // it's not number;
  }
}
```

Comment: I have to select each number from val (i.e, val[i]) and nee to identify its number or not.

Comment: that why I created a function rather than one liner. you can call it in for loop