# Can't calculate automatically Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

HTML

```
<select id="k1" onchange="kes1();" name="kelayakan1" size="1">
  <option value="">-- Pilih Salah Satu --</option>
  <option value="1">Layak</option>
  <option value="0">Tidak Layak</option>
</select>
<br>
<select id="k2" onchange="kes2();" name="kelayakan2" size="1">
  <option value="">-- Pilih Salah Satu --</option>
  <option value="1">Layak</option>
  <option value="0">Tidak Layak</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<table style="width:30%;" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="5">TES</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>B</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>
        <div id="aa1" class="layak" style="text-align:center;"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id="aa2" class="layak" style="text-align:center;"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>
        <div id="bb1" class="layak" style="text-align:center;"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id="bb2" class="layak" style="text-align:center;"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Result</td>
      <td>
        <div id="hasil1" style="text-align:center;"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id="hasil2" style="text-align:center;"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

JS

```
  function kes1() {
    var ap = document.getElementById('k1').value;
    var satu = 1;
    var nol = 0;
    if (ap == "1") {
      document.getElementById('aa1').innerHTML = satu;
      document.getElementById('aa2').innerHTML = nol;
    } else {
      document.getElementById('aa1').innerHTML = nol;
      document.getElementById('aa2').innerHTML = satu;
    }
  }
  function kes2() {
    var bp = document.getElementById('k2').value;
    var satu = 1;
    var nol = 0;

    if (bp == "1") {
      document.getElementById('bb1').innerHTML = satu;
      document.getElementById('bb2').innerHTML = nol;
    } else {
      document.getElementById('bb1').innerHTML = nol;
      document.getElementById('bb2').innerHTML = satu;
    }
  }
  $(document).ready(function() {
    //Iterate through each Textbox and add keyup event handler
    $(".layak").each(function() {
      $(this).innerHTML(function() {
        //Initialize total to 0
        var total = 0;
        $(".layak").each(function() {
          // Sum only if the text entered is number and greater than 0
          if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
            total += parseFloat(this.value);
          }
        });
        //Assign the total to label
        //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
        $("#hasil1").val(total);
      });
    });
  });
```

I want to calculate A1 and A2, B1 and B2 and appear on result..

if 1+0=1, if 1+1=2, if 0+0=0

but still can't working well :(

This jsfiddle.. https://jsfiddle.net/taraym/57Ltreb0/

may you know how to solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated your question with a working version https://jsfiddle.net/57Ltreb0/8/.

See [Is there any function like IsNumeric in javascript to validate numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9716468/is-there-any-function-like-isnumeric-in-javascript-to-validate-numbers) to understand the func `isNumeric` that I added

Let me know if it helps you.

Comment: but still can't calculate yaap.. okey.. i try it

Comment: i ceklis your answer .. when i'm solve this .. wait yaa @kasperite

Comment: I forgot to remove the `$(document).ready()` block. They don't actually do anything in this case

Comment: Try the link again and see if you are happy with it. You could refactor all the code to just one function but I will leave that to you :).

Comment: noo.. i want to calculate "vertical" a1 dan a2 .. not a1 dan b1

Comment: not sum(aa1.innerHTML, aa1.innerHTML,output1); but         sum(aa1.innerHTML, bb1.innerHTML,output1);

Comment: you just modified it yaa .. thank youu.. i just checklist your answer