# Parsing to Check if NAN Javascript

Tags: javascript, parsing, if-statement

I have an onclick even set up to take the value of an input and alert if the value is a number.  If the value of the input is blank, I am trying to alert it to say "No Number," however, it seems that even if my input it empty the function returns a statement saying the the "empty" value is indeed a number.

I have set variable up to parse the value of the input right away, but is this why my code is always returning "Is a number," because it's automatically set to be one when it collects the variable?

Code:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="numberTest" />

<button id="button">Click Me</button>
```

JS:

```
var button = document.getElementById("button");

button.onclick = function()
{
var numberTest = parseInt(document.getElementById("numberTest").value);

if(numberTest == NaN || "" || null)
{
    alert("No Number");
}
else
{
    alert("This is a number!");
}
};
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any function like IsNumeric in javascript to validate numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9716468/is-there-any-function-like-isnumeric-in-javascript-to-validate-numbers)

Comment: The duplicate of that is probably better actually [Validate decimal numbers in JavaScript - IsNumeric()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082/validate-decimal-numbers-in-javascript-isnumeric)

Comment: Thanks Liam, I'll check it out!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Checking if `== NaN` will always return `false`.  The proper way to do this is with [`Number.isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN):

```
var button = document.getElementById("button");

button.onclick = function() {
    var numberTest = parseInt(document.getElementById("numberTest").value);
    if (Number.isNaN(numberTest) || numberTest == "" || numberTest === null) {
        alert("No Number");
    }
    else {
        alert("This is a number!");
    }
};
```

You also had some issues with your logic in the `if` - each clause is a separate expression, and therefore needs to check against `numberTest` every time.

Answer (score 3):

Try using [isNaN()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) method:

```
isNaN(numberTest)
```

instead of

```
numberTest == NaN
```

According to [NaN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN), NaN is never equal NaN, so **NaN == NaN** or **NaN === NaN** will always return false...

BTW, you should change that:

```
if(numberTest == NaN || "" || null)
```

to this:

```
if(isNaN(numberTest) || numberTest == "" || numberTest == null)
```

so you always compare your variable to a value.

Answer (score 2):

This is another way to know if value is number or not

```
function IsANumber(numberToValidate) {
   return $.isNumeric(numberToValidate.replace(",", "").replace(".", ""));
} 
$("[id^=YourIDButton]").click(function(){
    if(IsANumber($(this).val())){
       alert("This is a number!");
    }else{
       alert("No number");
    }
}
```