# Number between double quotes

Tags: javascript, string, numbers

According to this code

```
function sayHi(myAge) {
    "use strict";
    if (isNaN(myAge)) {
        return "Ture";
    } else {
        return "False";
    }
}
sayHi("12");
```

isNan() return false, Why? "12" is not a number.

Because When I do this

```
var myAge = "12";
alert(myAge === 12);
```

it will return false, because "12" is a string but 12 a number.

Comment: What does `alert(myAge == 12)` return? "12" is converted into a number. When you check with === it is strict equality.

Comment: Are you trying to validate numbers?
Maybe you're looking for something like: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9716488/63011

Comment: @DominiqueLorre return `true` , That's what I am looking for, I am just want to figure out why isNan() return `false` for `"12"`

Comment: NaN is a special value, which means "undefined" or "not possible to display". Check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because NaN is a special value in JS, not a type. 
`sayHi(NaN)` will return true.

If you want to check if the value is the Number type, you should do

```
if (typeof myAge === "number")
```

And if you want to be sure, that it's not NaN as well, then

```
if (typeof myAge === "number" && !isNaN(myAge))
```

Comment: `NaN` is technically a `typeof` `"number"`

Comment: @SterlingArcher damn, sorry

Comment: So `"12"` isn't NaN but still a String type, Got it, Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

From [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.2.4):

> Returns true if the argument **coerces** to NaN, and otherwise returns false.

Compare to [===](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.6):

> If Type(x) is different from Type(y), return false.

Answer (score 1):

The isNaN() function determines whether a value is NaN or not. Note: coercion inside the isNaN function has interesting rules; you may alternatively want to use Number.isNaN(), as defined in ECMAScript 6, or you can **use typeof to determine if the value is Not-A-Number**.

**Reference :** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN