# Differentiate numbers and words in input using Regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to create a simple program that will allow the user to input numbers or words and have them sorted alphabetically (in case of words) or numerically (in case of numbers). For this I need an input that will differentiate between numbers and words so that for example 10, -10, 0.5 and -0.5 will be evaluated as numbers and everything else will be considered words.

So far I have come up with this:

```
function recordUserInput() {
  userInput = $('input').val();

  if (userInput.charAt(0).match(/^(-)?[0-9]/)) {
    console.log('number', userInput);
  }
  else {
    console.log('text', userInput);
  }

}
```

However, negative numbers are still evaluated as text.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I really think Joseph's answer is the best approach rather than regex. However, the reason your regex didn't work was because you used `charAt(0).match` against your regex. In the case of negative numbers, `charAt(0)` is `-`, so it will never match against `^(-)?[0-9]`. You should have simply used `userInput.match`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the unary `+`. If it returns `NaN`, it's not a number.

```
var type = isNaN(+userInput) ? 'text' : 'number';
```

`parseFloat` is probably not optimal. It parses left to right looking for a number and stops on a non-number. What it gathers, it turns to a number. `parseFloat('123a') === 123`.

Comment: And he needs to convert to number anyway to sort

Comment: Not need for `+`. `isNaN` works with strings as well.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `.charAt(0)` because you only look at the first character. Instead your regular expression is intended to look at the whole input, so just do (but add the `+` and `$` at the end):

```
if (userInput.match(/^-?[0-9]+$/)) {
```

Once you have put the inputs in an array, you can sort it like this (which also demonstrates how to better test for numbers):

```js
// Sample input:
var inputs = ['z', 1, 'a', 9, 3];

inputs.sort(function (a, b) {
    return isNaN(a) - isNaN(b) || isNaN(a) && a.localeCompare(b) || +a - +b;
});

console.log(inputs);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a small function `isNumeric()` to properly determine is a value is numeric. This is similar to the solution proposed in https://stackoverflow.com/a/9716488/1637175

```js
function isNumeric(val) {
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(val)) && isFinite(val);
}
```

Your original function becomes

```
function recordUserInput() {
    userInput = $('input').val();

    if ( isNumeric(userInput) ) {
        console.log('number', userInput);
    }
    else {
        console.log('text', userInput);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if an user input is a number or not, you can use something like this:

```
/^[-+]?\d+\.?\d*$/
```

it will match all number which might contain `-` or `+` at the beginning and dot symbol. Number like  `10`,`-10.0` and `+10.0`
[Example](https://regex101.com/r/Nb2iuC/1)