# How can i differentiate between a number and a special character?

Tags: javascript

```
value = "+"
isNaN(value)
```

Condition is false

```
value > 0
```

condition is true

```
value ="200"
isNaN(value)
```

Condition is false

```
value > 0
```

condition is true

Here's the thing, in both the cases `value > 0` shows `true`, i want to differentiate things like +-/* with numbers 0,200,5 etc.

is it possible to do this in Javascript??

Comment: check if `value` is a number type beforehand, then, apply equality operator and `isNaN` function

Comment: `"+" > 0` = false in JavaScript.  Also, if you need a way to check type then use `typeof`.  See the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof).

Comment: define special character? I wouldn't consider + a special character

Comment: when value="+", the second condition is not true as mentioned in question! so it seems that we didn't need that `isNaN` check at all?!

Comment: was trying to compare "+200" and that was causing the error,but thanks a lot for your input guys,really appreciate it,isNumeric thing worked :) and changed the logic to read "+ 200" instead of "+200"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Seems to be working as you are wanting/expecting.

```js
value = "+";
// is true as "+" isn't a number
console.log(isNaN(value));
// is false because "+" isn't greater than 0
console.log(value > 0);

value = "200";
// is false, because value is a number
console.log(isNaN(value));
// is true because "200" is greater than 0
console.log(value > 0);
```

---

### However, you could implement a [`isNumeric`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9716468/is-there-any-function-like-isnumeric-in-javascript-to-validate-numbers) function

```js
function isNumeric(n) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}

value = "+";
// is false because "+" isn't numeric
console.log(isNumeric(value));
// is false because "+" isn't greater than 0
console.log(value > 0);

value = "200";
// is true, because value is numeric
console.log(isNumeric(value));
// is true, because "200" is greater than 0
console.log(value > 0);
```

---

### Or you can use typeof

```js
value = "+";
// is false as "+" is a string
console.log(typeof(value) === "number");
// is false because "+" isn't greater than 0
console.log(value > 0);

value = "200";
// is false, because value is a string not a number
console.log(typeof(value) === "number");
// is true because "200" is greater than 0, this auto converts to 200
console.log(value > 0);
```

---

### Regex with numbers and symbols

```js
function symbolCompare(value) {
  var results = /(\+|\-)(\d+)/.exec(value);
  if(results) {
    return results[2];
  }
  
  return false;
}

value = "+200";
// is false because 200 is a number
console.log(isNaN(symbolCompare(value)));
// is true because 200 > 0
console.log(symbolCompare(value) > 0);

value = "-200";
// is false because 200 is a number
console.log(isNaN(symbolCompare(value)));
// is true because 200 > 0
console.log(symbolCompare(value) > 0);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help,going to use the isNumeric thing :),i was trying to compare "+200" and that was causing the error

Comment: if you need to compare "+200" we'll want to use regex, something like what i added in the answer

Comment: this simplifies many things,thanks a lot,i wrote a logic for detecting "+ 200" now this might come handy