# Javascript document.getElementByID with condition

Tags: javascript, html

I'm reading from a text file some numbers. Sometimes there's a number 0 and the line below outputs 0, but I don't want to output if the number is "0". Is there a way to change the line below to NOT output/print when the number is "0"? Thanks

```
document.getElementById('inputText').innerHTML= "(" + parseFloat(output1*2).toFixed(3) + "," +  parseFloat(output2*2).toFixed(3) + ")";
```

Comment: `if ( yourNumber != '0' ) { document.getElementById( ... ) }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a function that checks each value and generates a result based on that, like this:

```js
var getResult = function (num1, num2) {
  var result1 = num1 ? (parseFloat(num1) * 2).toFixed(3) : "";
  result1 = isNaN(result1) ? "" : result1;
  var result2 = num2 ? (parseFloat(num2) * 2).toFixed(3) : "";
  result2 = isNaN(result2) ? "" : result2;
  var comma = result1 && result2 ? ", " : "";
  return `(${result1}${comma}${result2})`;
};

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML += `5, 0 = ${getResult("5")}<br/>`;
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML += `0, 4 = ${getResult("0", "4")}<br/>`;
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML += `3, 2 = ${getResult("3", "2")}<br/>`;
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML += `3, 2 = ${getResult("three", "15.5")}<br/>`;
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Edit: Removed possible NaN-results.

Comment: @AlexaAtna If something that can't be resolved to a float by `parseFloat`, this will return `NaN`, so depending on how you use it you might want to add validation for this. For an `isNumeric` function in javascript, check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9716468/is-there-any-function-like-isnumeric-in-javascript-to-validate-numbers

Comment: @AlexaAtna Excluding NaN-results is now included in the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace 0 with nothing using the or operator:

```
parseFloat(output1*2) || ""
```

or using a ternary:

```
output1? parseFloat(output1*2).toFixed(3) : ""
```

Answer (score 0):

Use if statement to check your number:

Html:

```
<p id="inputText">
   0
</p>
```

Js:

```
var output  = document.getElementById('inputText').innerHTML;
output = parseFloat(output);
if(output  != '0'){
inputText.innerHTML= "(" + (output *2)
.toFixed(3) + "," +  (output*2).toFixed(3) + ")";
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/b5st3h2m/2/

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementById('inputText').innerHTML= "(" + ((parseFloat(output1*2).toFixed(3) + ",") ? parseFloat(1*2).toFixed(3):"") +  ((parseFloat(output2*2).toFixed(3)) ? parseFloat(1*2).toFixed(3):"") + ")";