# Validate a number input with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to validate my form information using javascript. My form has an amount value that must be entered as a number. I am trying to make it so a number must be inputted but I cannot quite get down the issue I am having with my javascript function

```
<form name="formname" onsubmit="return checkNumInput()" action="nextpage.php" method="post">

function checkNumInput(){
    number.constructor;
    var amount = document.forms["formname"]["amount"];
    if(Number.isNaN(amount.value)){
        window.alert("amount must be a number");
        amount.focus();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Just use `<input type="number">` and the user won't be able to enter anything but numbers.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Okay, but out of curiousity,how would it work with javascript?

Comment: `Number.isNaN` only checks to see if the passed value is `===NaN` not if something cant be converted to a number. You probably meant to use the global `isNaN`

Comment: what does `number.constructor;` do?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9716468/pure-javascript-a-function-like-jquerys-isnumeric

Answer (score 2):

If you ain't planning to use native HTML5 number input, with JavaScript is as easy as this:

```js
const input = document.querySelector("#numbers");

input.addEventListener("keydown", verifyKey);

function verifyKey(e) {
  if(isNaN(+e.key) && e.key!="Backspace"){
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="numbers">
```

Comment: really really sleek