# How can I apply sorting only when data attributes match?

Tags: jquery

I have a sort function which uses data-attributes to re-arrange the `items` in the `list` for each `table`. The problem with my code is that if the value of the `data-head` isn't the same for each list the sort breaks down and appends all of the second column items into the same list.

In this example when I click Price or Size, both types items are appended to each list even though they have a different `data-status`.

How do I change the sort to only apply to each `table` when the `data-sort` matches the `data-head`?

```js
var keys = [...$(".table .btn")].map((i) => $(i).text());
var arr = [...$(".list .item")].map((i) => {
  var data = $(i).find("[data-sort]");
  var obj = {};
  for (let id = 0; id < data.length; id++) {
    obj[keys[id]] = data.eq(id).text();
    obj.line = $(i)[0].outerHTML;
  }
  return obj;
});

//console.log("arr",  arr);        

var lastkey = -1;
$(".table .btn").on("click", function() {
  var keytosort = keys[Number($(".table .btn").index(this))];
  var desc = true;
  if (keytosort == lastkey) {
    desc = true;
    lastkey = -1;
  } else {
    desc = false;
    lastkey = keytosort;
  }


  arr = arr.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a[keytosort].startsWith("$")) {
      let an = a[keytosort].substring(1); //put off $
      let bn = b[keytosort].substring(1);
      return Number(an) - Number(bn);
    } else {
      return a[keytosort].localeCompare(b[keytosort]);
    }
  }); //end sort

  if (desc) arr = arr.reverse();

  //recreate the different items
  $(".list").children().remove();

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    $(".list").append(arr[i].line);
  }
});
```

```css
.list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.item,
.header {
  display: flex;
}

.btn {
  cursor: pointer;
}

[data-sort] {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="btn" data-head='country'>Country</div>
    <div class="btn" data-head='price'>Price</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="list">
      <div class="item">
        <div data-sort="country">France</div>
        <div data-sort="price">$25</div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div data-sort="country">Spain</div>
        <div data-sort="price">$30</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="table">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="btn" data-head='country'>Country</div>
    <div class="btn" data-head='type'>Size</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="list">
      <div class="item">
        <div data-sort="country">France</div>
        <div data-sort="type">small</div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div data-sort="country">spain</div>
        <div data-sort="price">large</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Would be a lot easier if you just isolated items per table. `$('.btn').click(function(){ const items = $(this).closest('.table').find('.item')... })`

Comment: @charlietfl would you be able to provide a working snippet for your solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By creating an array of tables, it is possible to separate the `keys` and `arr` values for each table so that they can be sorted independently.

The below example also adds logic to adjust for cases where the sort had no effect.

EDIT: Updated to include an example table with numeric prices only.

```js
var tables = [...$(".table")].map((t) => {
  var keys = [...$(t).find(".btn")].map((i) => $(i).text());
  var arr = [...$(t).find(".list .item")].map((i) => {
    var data = $(i).find("[data-sort]");
    var obj = {};
    for (let id = 0; id < data.length; id++) {
      obj[keys[id]] = data.eq(id).text();
      obj.line = $(i)[0].outerHTML;
    }
    return obj;
  });
  
  return { keys: keys, arr: arr, lastkey: -1 };
})
    

$(".table .btn").on("click", function() {
  var table = $(this.closest(".table"));
  var i = Number($(".table").index(table));
  var tabletosort = tables[i];
  var keytosort = tabletosort.keys[Number(table.find(".btn").index(this))];
  var desc = true;
  
  if (keytosort == tables[i].lastkey) {
    desc = true;
    tables[i].lastkey = -1;
  } else {
    desc = false;
    tables[i].lastkey = keytosort;
  }

  tabletosort.arr = tabletosort.arr.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a[keytosort].startsWith("$")) {
      let an = a[keytosort].substring(1); //put off $
      let bn = b[keytosort].substring(1);
      return Number(an) - Number(bn);
    } else if (!isNaN(parseFloat(a[keytosort])) && isFinite(a[keytosort]) && !isNaN(parseFloat(b[keytosort])) && isFinite(b[keytosort])) {
      return Number(a[keytosort]) - Number(b[keytosort]);
    } else {
      return a[keytosort].localeCompare(b[keytosort]);
    }
  }); //end sort
  
  //if sorting made no difference, reverse the result
  if(0 == tabletosort.arr.reduce((total, item, j) => total + (item == tables[i].arr[j] ? 0 : 1), 0)) {
    tabletosort.arr = tabletosort.arr.reverse();
  }

  if (desc) tabletosort.arr = tabletosort.arr.reverse();

  //recreate the different items
  table.find(".list").children().remove();

  for (let i = 0; i < tabletosort.arr.length; i++) {
    table.find(".list").append(tabletosort.arr[i].line);
  }
});
```

```css
.list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.item,
.header {
  display: flex;
}

.btn {
  cursor: pointer;
}

[data-sort] {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="btn" data-head='country'>Country</div>
    <div class="btn" data-head='price'>Price</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="list">
      <div class="item">
        <div data-sort="country">France</div>
        <div data-sort="price">$25</div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div data-sort="country">Spain</div>
        <div data-sort="price">$30</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="table">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="btn" data-head='country'>Country</div>
    <div class="btn" data-head='type'>Size</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="list">
      <div class="item">
        <div data-sort="country">France</div>
        <div data-sort="type">small</div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div data-sort="country">spain</div>
        <div data-sort="price">large</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="table">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="btn" data-head='country'>Country</div>
    <div class="btn" data-head='price'>Price</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="list">
      <div class="item">
        <div data-sort="country">France</div>
        <div data-sort="price">150</div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div data-sort="country">Spain</div>
        <div data-sort="price">250</div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div data-sort="country">Germany</div>
        <div data-sort="price">30</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I just noticed that if you remove the "$" from the numbers in the table it doesn't sort based on the value of the number. It only takes the first digit and not the entire number.

Comment: @KyleUnderhill good point! I've updated the sorting logic (added the `else if`) with a numeric check based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9716468/pure-javascript-a-function-like-jquerys-isnumeric) to handle that case.

Comment: I tested your updated code using the numbers 150, 250, and 30 and it sorts in this exact order as it takes the first integer only and not the entire number.